# Form Post via ASP.NET MVC on a Mac Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, post

I have code that does a simple form post in a new window from our web application that calls out to an Action on a ASP.NET MVC3 Controller.  This behavior works just fine on PC Browsers but if a user is on a Mac the form post causes the browser to download a Zero byte file with the name of the Action that is being requested.

The action looks  up an item from the database and based on its Format returns a FileContentResult with the correct content type and the item's data.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and any workarounds they've found when running into this?

```
if (item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.PDF || item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.XDP)
{
    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data), "application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml");
}

if (item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.XFDL)
{
    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item.Data), "application/vnd.xfdl");
}

if (item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.CSV)
{
    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data), "application/CSV")
    {
        FileDownloadName = item.FileName
    };
}

if (item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.HTML)
{
    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data), "text/html");
}

if (item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.TXT)
{
    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data), "text/plain");
}

if (item.Format == PrintedItemFormat.XFDF)
{
    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data), "application/vnd.adobe.xfdf");
}
```

Comment: Code please? Otherwise we're just throwing darts at the problem blind-folded.

Comment: What code would you like to see?  The Action?

Comment: Be nice to see how you're opening it on the client-side.  It's likely not getting to the action.  Have you used any browser developer tools to see if the request is actually being made?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Mac browsers need to know a FileDownloadName as it cannot be inferred via the request.